# phpize: m4 error just in one extension

Tags: php, sendmail

On Linux, I installed php 5.3.8 from source. Using phpize for installing an extension works fine but not on one specific extension (mysqlnd).

```
# cd /opt/php/5.3.8/ext/pdo && /opt/php/5.3.8/bin/phpize
... this runs ok
# cd /opt/php/5.3.8/ext/mysqlnd && /opt/php/5.3.8/bin/phpize
Cannot find config.m4. 
Make sure that you run '/opt/php/5.3.8/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module`
```

As you can see error can not be that I am not on top level source directory since I am. I tried to call phpize from ext folder - did not work either! For info I have m4 installed

Any idea? Thanks :)

Comment: http://kmaiti.blogspot.com/2010/08/cannot-find-configm4-phpize-resolved.html

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that mysqlnd's m4 file is not `config.m4` but config9.m4. This is a dependency mechanism, to ensure `buildconf` puts it at the end of configure. One might argue that `phpize` should know about this, currently it doesn't.

A work-around is to rename config9.m4 to config.m4, but mind that a "normal" build won't work then.

Note also that PHP 5.3.8 doesn't allow `mysqlnd` to be built shared, so above work-around won't work. This will be allowed in PHP 5.3.9, though. This still not solve the config.m4 vs. config9.m4 issue, but for PHP you will be able to do `--enable-mysqlnd=shared` to receive `mysqlnd.so` as part of the main PHP build.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run phpize from mysql folder

You can check the same post here : http://kmaiti.blogspot.com/2010/08/cannot-find-configm4-phpize-resolved.html

Comment: I hear you well, these kind of errors happen when you run phpize from ext instead than from the extension folder. That's what I do and it does not work :(